# Filtering between two values

Tags: lightning

I have an issue where I need to filter between two fields, but can't find an elegant/quick way to do so.[image: Screenshot of LVR Min / Max fields]

I have "Min LVR" and "Max LVR", which can vary a lot.
I don't want to filter by either of these.  I want our Users to be able to input LVR, and it filters objects where LVR is between Min LVR & Max LVR.

So if I input "LVR = 74%", it would show results where "Min LVR = 0%" and "Max LVR = 80%", but also where "Min LVR = 70%" and "Max LVR = 75%", as an example.

My thoughts/findings so far:

- I don't believe there's a quick/easy native way to do this (although I'm hoping I'm wrong).
- I tried making a custom object "Loan Product Filter".  Input "LVR" in there, then show a related list based off that.  But it seems Salesforce doesn't allow parent fields within the dynamic list filter comparitor.
- I've also tried using the CMTD Enhanced list. The issue with this: it seems the items must be directly related.  If I directly relate all Loan Products to one Filter Object, then I believe all Users filters will be intertwined.  It just seems like a messy solution.
- You can have the user input "Min LVR less than or equal to 74%" and "Max LVR greater than or equal to 74%" - but this is very cumbersome on the User and isn't a great solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Uh, surely you just need `LVR >= MinLVR AND LVR < MaxLVR` as two parts of the filter? This is the base logic needed to satisfy "in range checking". There is no way to provide your own function for use in filters that will make it "easier" to do.